# Passing kwargs from Resource to widget

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I've been working with django import_export and I wanted to pass kwargs from the resource to the clean field of my custom widget validator. how can i do that
here's my code

resources.py

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    identifier = Field(
        column_name="identifier",
        attribute="identifier",
        widget=RegexWidget(),
    )
    class Meta:
        model=User
```

widgets.py

```
class RegexWidget(CharWidget):
   def clean(self, value, row=None, **kwargs):
        regex = kwargs.get("regex", None)
        ...
```

In the test I've tries something like the following

```
UserResource.import_data(dataset, regex=r"U\{4}d\Z")
```

but the kwargs from the clean method of the widget is {}

Comment: It looks like the `kwargs` are only passed to `before_insert_row` and `after_insert_row`: https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/e5f5b3cb842b8a2336fc4a6927b2297223fc2a72/import_export/resources.py#L775-L777 and the kwargs to `import_object` are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to pass the regex to the Widget constructor.

```py
class RegexWidget(CharWidget):
    def __init__(self, regex):
        self.regex = regex
    
    def clean(self, value, row=None, **kwargs):
        regex = self.regex
        # ...
        return super().clean(value, row, **kwargs)

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    identifier = Field(
        column_name="identifier",
        attribute="identifier",
        widget=RegexWidget(r"U\{4}d\Z"),
    )
    class Meta:
        model=User
```

The [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#field-widgets) have more detail on this.